# ASP.Net MVC routing with RouteConstraint not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Just when I think I have routing figured out, it doesn't work the way I think it should.  I'm using ASP.Net MVC 4 RC.  Here's my RouteConfig:

```
        routes.MapRoute
        (
            "TwoIntegers",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id1}/{id2}",
            new { controller = "Gallery", action = "Index", id1 = new Int32Constraint(), id2 = new Int32Constraint() }
        );

        routes.MapRoute
        (
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Here's my route constraint:

```
public class Int32Constraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (values.ContainsKey(parameterName))
        {
            int intValue;
            return int.TryParse(values[parameterName].ToString(), out intValue) && (intValue != int.MinValue) && (intValue != int.MaxValue);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

/{domain.com}/PageSection/Edit/21

It is getting stopped at the "TwoIntegers" route.  It's very clear there's not a second integer being passed.

**Here's my error:**

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in
>   'SolutiaConsulting.Web.ContentManager.Controllers.PageSectionController'.
>   An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

What am I doing wrong?  I have the more specific route listed first.  Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constraints are not correctly specified. Make sure you are using the correct overload of the `MapRoute` extension method:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "TwoIntegers",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id1}/{id2}",
    new { controller = "Gallery", action = "Index" },
    new { id1 = new Int32Constraint(), id2 = new Int32Constraint() }
);
```

Notice the 4th argument that is used to specify constraints, not the 3rd.

Btw, you could make your code more readable using named parameters:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "TwoIntegers",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id1}/{id2}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Gallery", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { id1 = new Int32Constraint(), id2 = new Int32Constraint() }
);
```

Also how about a regex?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "TwoIntegers",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id1}/{id2}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Gallery", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { id1 = @"\d+", id2 = @"\d+" }
);
```

Comment: wouldn't the regex solution have problems with overflow integer values? e.g. if a user enters a value for id1 or id2 bigger than Int32.MaxValue, would it break?